# use `QNetworkAccessManager` post request

Tags: qt, network-programming

i use `QNetworkAccessManager` post request to a website:

```
    void Spider::getProducts()
    {
        connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(getProducts(QNetworkReply*)));

        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.example.com/query"));

        for(int i = 0; i < categories.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(categories[i].isCategory())
            {
                isSubCategory = false;

                emit manager.finished(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                for(int page_number = 0; page_number < categories[i].getPageCount(); ++i)
                {
                    isSubCategory = true;

                    QJsonObject json;

                    json.insert("NValue", categories[i].getNValue());
                    json.insert("NodeId", categories[i].getNodeId());
                    json.insert("StoreId", categories[i].getStoreId());
                    json.insert("StoreType", categories[i].getStoreType());
                    json.insert("PageNumber", ++page_number);
                    json.insert("SubCategoryId", categories[i].getSubCategoryId());

                    QJsonDocument doc;

                    doc.setObject(json);

                    QByteArray request_body = doc.toJson();

                    manager.post(request, request_body);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

when i run this program, at beginning, this program run normally, after running for a while, it will stop: neither terminated nor continue to run. i can not figure out why it behavior like this? is there anything that needed to be noticed when use `QNetworkAccess`? or i am refused by that website? ...

Comment: What do you mean it will stop, have you tried pausing it with debugger, where exactly execution is stopped if you do that? What replies are you getting?

Comment: @Predelink under normal situation, the program will print the response content. when it `stopped`, it do nothing: neither terminated nor continue to print the response content. no error display also.

Comment: Well firstly you should really try using debugger to figure things out, that's the most reliable way to find what's wrong. Secondly, I don't see any obvious problem in your code but sending finished signal of `QNetworkAccessManager` yourself seems kinda strange.

Comment: @Predelink because if the categorys[i] isn't a subcategory, there is no need to post request for it, so i just emit a finished signal pretend the request for it has been finished...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same QNetworkAccessManager object in a loop multiple times. It is incorrect. For each separate post request you need a separate QNetworkAccessManager object if you want to send requests in parallel. Else if you only want to use a single instance then you need to serialize your post requests by sending next post request when the previous ends in the finished slot.

**Updated:** Try out this code, it uses single QNetworkAccessManager object, you will need to check for correct place of i++ as per your needs

```
connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
this, SLOT(getProducts(QNetworkReply*))); // add this to constructor of your program

void Spider::getProducts()
    {
        static int i = 0;
        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.example.com/query"));

        while(categories[i].isCategory())
        {
            isSubCategory = false;
            i++;
        }
        if(i == categories.size())
        {
           emit allPostRequestsDone();
           return;
        }

            else
            {
                i++;
                if(page_number < categories[i].getPageCount())
                {
                    isSubCategory = true;

                    QJsonObject json;

                    json.insert("NValue", categories[i].getNValue());
                    json.insert("NodeId", categories[i].getNodeId());
                    json.insert("StoreId", categories[i].getStoreId());
                    json.insert("StoreType", categories[i].getStoreType());
                    json.insert("PageNumber", ++page_number);
                    json.insert("SubCategoryId", categories[i].getSubCategoryId());

                    QJsonDocument doc;

                    doc.setObject(json);

                    QByteArray request_body = doc.toJson();

                    manager.post(request, request_body);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since `QNetworkAccessManager` uses asynchronous and queues the requests I don't believe there's any need for multiple of them. Also there's explicit line in Qt documentation:  "One QNetworkAccessManager should be enough for the whole Qt application."

Comment: @Predelnik I have been using this class since last 3 years, what you are referring to it is http-pipelining upto six parallel request, but that is not related to your case. In your case you need to wait for each post request to complete before sending the next if you only want to use one object.

Comment: @adana kamili i create a `QNetworkAccessManager` object in loop body, when the loop body executed, it will construct a new object. but the result is same as before, the program also stopped...